# What does: "error: invalid command 'bdist'" mean?

Tags: python-2.7, executable, pyinstaller, py2exe

I'm trying to convert a python script into a standalone executable, and it stops at `"error: invalid command 'bdist'"`with both cx_freeze as well as with py installer.

I can not find what this error means, would you have any suggestions?

As requested in the comment, this is the main code, in `Renaming_variables2` an external file is called, and if I don't add that file it gives an error. I think that implies exe runs at least untill that line. Then when I add the external file to it's requested location, that file-missing error is removed and the `bdist` error shows up. Without any line indication.

```
#Define variables
#Parameters:

import psutil
import os
import sys
import shutil
import time
print("the directory of the python installation =  ", os.path)
print("the working directory of this project  = ", os.getcwd())
print("the directory of this py  = ", os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))


breaktime = 11
refresh_time = 2
nr_of_task_scheduler_commands = list() 
for i in range(0,2):
    nr_of_task_scheduler_commands.append(False)
name_check_md = "d.py" 

convert_name_check_md = "Convert_d_py2exe.py"
path_name_check_md_and_conversion = "a/"


file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
file_path =file_path .replace('\\','/')
name_run_check = "ma.py" 

convert_run_check = "Convert_s_py2exe.py"
path_run_check_and_conversion = "b/"
path_task = "task"
path_task_adm = "/adm"
name_original_task = "task.xml"
name_task = "task.xml"
temp_name_task = "taskq.xml"
adm_run_bat = "RunAsAdminConsole.bat"
output_adm= "/output_adm"
add_task_bat = "callrunasadminconsole4.bat"

import getpass
user_name = getpass.getuser()

import socket
domain = socket.getfqdn()

destination_path = "C:/out"

parent_output = 'output'
parent_dist = 'dist/'

#Not replaced below
name_check_md_exe = "ds.exe"
#Not replaced below
path_check_md_exe = "a/dist/"
name_run_check_exe = "dc.exe"
#Not replaced below
path_run_check_exe = "b/dist/"
#Not replaced below
path_min = "sx"
path_gmin = "dr"

md_output = "output.txt"



import getpass
print getpass.getuser()





#check if folder exists and if not, create it
if not os.path.exists(destination_path):
    print destination_path + " is not an existing path"
    # 1.0 if non-existant goto step 2
# 1.1 if existant: go to step 3.
# 2. read manual path from: "path.txt"
    destination_path = raw_input("Please enter a new system path ")

# 3. feed path into Renaming_variables.py
# 4. run Renaming_variables.py


# Disable printing
def blockPrint():
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

import Renaming_variables2

# 5. run callerY.py
import caller5

os.chdir(file_path +'/'+ path_task+path_task_adm)

os.startfile("RunAsAdminConsole.bat")

#1.a #first delete destination file from /task if it exists
def deletion(file_path, old_file_name):
    try:
        # delete all files in folder
        file_and_folder_path = os.path.join(file_path, old_file_name)
        os.remove(file_and_folder_path)
    except:
        pass

deletion(file_path +'/'+ path_task,"RunAsAdminConsole.exe")

#1.b #then move file to /task
time.sleep(10)
shutil.move(file_path +'/'+ path_task+path_task_adm+output_adm+'/'+"RunAsAdminConsole.exe" , file_path +'/'+ path_task+'/')

os.chdir(file_path +'/'+ path_task+'/')

os.startfile("callrunasadminconsole4.bat")
```

However, I would like to stress that this question is not about solving that problem, this question is about the meaning of the following error message:

```
error: invalid command 'bdist'
```

Comment: Could you please post some code from your main python file? The `bdist` is possibly supplied by `setuptools`, but it would be useful to have more information.